# Passing URL parameter with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have some JavaScript that creates Forward and Back buttons. However, I need to pass a parameter in the URL (`?id=$idd`):

```
<a href="javascript:submitForm('mainForm','back');" title="Go back to the kit home page" style="float: left;"><img src="images/back.gif" alt="Go back to the kit home page" border="0" /></a>
<a href="javascript:submitForm('mainForm','proceed');" title="Submit the order details" style="float: right;"><img src="images/proceed.gif" alt="Proceed to the next page" border="0" /></a>
```

The JavaScript is below:

```
// Used in all pages to submit a form and optionally set a hidden 
// form varaible called 'navigate' to direct navgiation
function submitForm(formName, navigateValue) {
    if (navigateValue != null && navigateValue != "") {
        document.forms[formName].navigate.value = navigateValue;
    }
    document.forms[formName].submit();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well my question is how do I pass a varible in the URL, ie when proceed is clicked it goes to the next page with the varible in the URL - http://www.xxxx.com/next-page.php?id=1329

Comment: Which variable though: navigateValue? "?id=$idd"? Other?

Comment: Is there a reason for why you use a form?

Comment: im currently using:

<form action="orderConfirmation.php" method="POST" name="mainForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="navigate" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>"/>

but this doesn't pass the id onto the next script as buildOrder.php is also the location of the form - it validates itself then moves onto the next script - orderConfirmation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the variable to the url your `<form>` points to:

```
<form action="example.com?id=14">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at what you're asking, and it doesn't make much sense because if you're submitting a form, why wouldn't you put the data in the form, but it sounds like you just need to modify the forms' **action** property. Something like:

```
document.forms[formName].action += "?id=$idd";
```

But this depends strongly on the existing action value and you will probably want to sanitise that with a validating method.